# Why are fb-messenger scheme urls not working within facebook app browser?

Tags: facebook, url-scheme

I have a page with a link like fb-messenger://share/?link=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.nhl.com. The scheme works from a browser but nothing happens when the page is viewed from within the Facebook app in the Facebook app browser. I would expect it to open Facebook Messenger (and provide a better experience than the browser).

Does the Facebook app browser not support fb-messenger scheme?

Didn't have much luck finding other solutions, perhaps there is a better way of sharing to FB Messenger from a web page?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem... Have you found any solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately I did not.